# Extracting Work From Mixing Of Ideal Gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Consider two identical boxes of ideal gases, at the same temperature, volume, and pressure. I will assume that gas A and gas B are distinguishable, but do not react with each other (maybe this is a lie).

We remove a wall between the two boxes. The gases will tend to mix over time, since that tends to increase entropy.

Because entropy is increasing, Gibbs energy should be decreasing. I have read that "The Gibbs free energy change is the maximum amount of non-expansion work that can be extracted from a closed system."

However, in my example, where there is no change in enthalpy, I don't see how the work can be extracted from simply the change in entropy (the arrangement of the gases).

Clearly I have missed something, as I am new to these terms. I hope my question is not too naive.

Comment: [Determining change in entropy and enthalpy during mixing of gases](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62164/determining-change-in-entropy-and-enthalpy-during-mixing-of-gases)

Comment: You need to devise a reversible process for going from two individual gases at T, P , and V to a mixture of the gases as T, P, and 2V (and partial pressures P/2).  Hint:  such a process might involve use of semipermeable membranes and three cylinders.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing of ideal gases is just two expansion processes into the same final volume. Replace the partition with one permeable to gas B but not gas A, and using a piston permeable to gas A but not gas B, collect the work from B reversibly expanding into the final volume. Then switch pistons to one permeable to gas B but not to gas A, remove the partition, and collect the reversible work from A expanding. No entropy is ever generated, and you extracted work, in accordance with the difference in Gibbs free energies.